# C# timer is not working

Tags: c#, timer

I got a form in C#, and I dropped a timer on it. I can see the timer being declared in form1.designer.cs but it's not visible on the form UI.
Anyways, I added the timer code to the form1_load event, and then added a timer1_tick_1 event.
But for some reason, the messageBox specified inside the timer1_tick_1 event is not coming up.
The form loads and just sits there, doing nothing.
Did I miss some statement or is the timer not added/dropped properly to the form?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 2000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();

            }
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}//timer
```

Comment: did you actually wire up your event?

Comment: What type is the timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you forgot to attach your event handler to the Tick event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick_1;
timer1.Interval = 2000;
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Adding the timer to the tick event worked. Does this mean that I can have multiple timers in the same program?